# Instanciar lista e Inserir valores em diferentes momentos

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Olá, em uma aplicação web, preciso inserir valores em uma lista em diferentes momentos. Essa inserção se dá após o usuário preencher campos na página e dar o submit no formulário.

No submit é chamado o método que insere os valores na lista.

No método tenho que instanciar a lista para inserir os valores, mas a cada vez é instanciado uma nova lista e perco a anterior.

Segue o código que estou tentando formular:

```
public static List<LanctoConferenciaCaixaModel> LanctoValorConferencia(string parDsFormaPagto, decimal parVlConferido)
{
    List<LanctoConferenciaCaixaModel> listLancamentoCaixa = null;

    if (listLancamentoCaixa == null)
    {
        listLancamentoCaixa = new List<LanctoConferenciaCaixaModel>();
    }

    listLancamentoCaixa.Add(new LanctoConferenciaCaixaModel()
    {
        dsFormaPgto = parDsFormaPagto,
        vlConferido = parVlConferido
    });

    return listLancamentoCaixa;
}
```

Acredito que meu problema seja no if que testa se a lista está null.

PS: Iniciei com programação C# a apenas 3 meses. :)

Comment: Você está declarando uma lista nula e então imediatamente verificando se a mesma é nula. Então, sempre o bloco `if` será executado, e `listLancamentoCaixa` será uma lista nova.

Comment: a lista é atributo de alguma classe? como você usa ela fora do método?

Comment: @CypherPotato, bem observado, copiei o código de outro lugar e acabei não percebendo isso... porém removendo a declaração nula, no if acusa "Uso de variável local não atribuída".

Comment: @AndersonNuernberg atribua uma instância a ela pois então: `var listLancamentoCaixa = new List<LanctoConferenciaCaixaModel>();`

Comment: @CypherPotato, ai eu caio exatamente na minha questão inicial, a cada vez que chamo o método, ele instancia uma uma lista, e perco os valores já inseridos. O if é seria exatamente para ver se já havia uma instância da lista e adicionar novos valores.

Comment: precisa mover a declaração da variável para outro escopo, na classe por exemplo, senão vai criar novamente sempre uma vez que a lista é uma variável local, que se perde quando processa a página. Tente movê-la para o escopo de classe, fora do método

Comment: @RicardoPontual mesmo movendo para fora do método, ao testar o if se é nulo, entra e cria uma nova instância, perdendo os valores já informados.

Comment: isso deve acontecer pq a cada request é instanciada a classe da página novamente, você pode resolver isso, apenas para esse exemplo (isso não é melhor forma de fazer) declarando a variável como estática `static List<LanctoConferenciaCaixaModel> listLancamentoCaixa = null;`. Se não souber o que é uma variável static, sugiro procurar aqui no site

Comment: @RicardoPontual, sua dica de declarar a variável como estática deu certo nesse caso pra que eu preciso. Obrigado.

Answer (score -1):

Bom dia.
Como os amigos falaram, você está perdendo o conteúdo da lista pois cria uma nova instância da mesma a cada execução do método "LanctoValorConferencia()".

Encontrei este exemplo aqui ([Singleton X Classes Estáticas - Macoratti](http://www.macoratti.net/18/06/c_singstat1.htm)) que pode te ajudar para adquirir mais conhecimento, porém também desenvolvi algo pensando no cenário que você passou.

Acabei não testando a implementação, qualquer dúvida pode perguntar.

```
/* Sua entidade */
public class LanctoConferenciaCaixaModel
{
  public string dsFormaPgto { get; set; }
  public decimal vlConferido { get; set; }

  public LanctoConferenciaCaixaModel(string formaPagto, decimal vlConferido)
  {
    dsFormaPgto = formaPagto;
    vlConferido = vlConferido;
  }
}

/* Esta classe guarda uma instancia da sua lista, desta maneira a mesma pode ser recuperada em diversos locais diferentes. */
public sealed class ConferenciaSingleton
{
  static ConferenciaSingleton _instancia
  public static ConferenciaSingleton Instancia { get return _instancia ?? (_instancia = new ConferenciaSingleton()); }

  private ConferenciaSingleton() {}
  public List<LanctoConferenciaCaixaModel> listLancamentoCaixa { get; set; }
}

/* Classe que adiciona novos lancamentos */
public List<LancamentoConferenciaCaixaModel> LanctoValorConferencia(string parDsFormaPagto, decimal parVlConferido)
{
  var variavelConferencia = ConferenciaSingleton.Instancia;

  var lancto = new LanctoConferenciaCaixaModel(parDsFormaPagto, parVlConferido);

  if (variavelConferencia.listLancamentoCaixa == null)
    variavelConferencia.listLancamentoCaixa = new List<LanctoConferenciaCaixaModel>();

  variavelConferencia.listLancamentoCaixa.Add(lancto);
}
```

Comment: Eduardo, agradeço sua imensa ajuda, mas aqui no meu projeto não certo, mas entendi seu código e com certeza vou aproveitar algo no futuro. A sugestão acima do Ricardo deu certo nesse momento para o que preciso fazer... ainda vou realizar mais testes e desenvolver o restante da tela. Caso precise de algo volto a pedir ajuda. Mais uma vez Obrigado.